# How to parameterized implicit curve.

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

How could I parameterize:
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(x^2+y^2\right)-\frac{1}{3}x^3=\frac{1}{6}$$
as $x(t)$ and $y(t)$?

Comment: You could just solve for $y$... is this homework? Do you know that such a parameterization will exist?

Comment: I can't solve for $y$. I need the parameterization to compute an integral. I assume it's existence because otherwise I don't know how to solve a problem that requires this parameterization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving for $y$ gives $$y=\pm \sqrt{\frac{1+2x^3-3x^2}{3}}=\pm\frac{(x-1)\sqrt{2x+1}}{\sqrt 3}$$  Let $$x=\frac{t^2-1}{2}$$ so that $$2x+1=t^2$$ Then $$y=\pm\frac{(t^2-3)(t)}{2\sqrt 3}$$ That gives you a parameterization in two pieces. EDIT: Actually, just pick one of the signs. Then you have a parameterization of the whole curve if my graph is right.